# Variances by row values depending on primary key

Tags: powerbi, dax

| acc.num | Balance | Period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 200 | 1 |
| 2345 | 300 | 1 |
| 1234 | 300 | 2 |
| 2345 | 200 | 2 |

Is there a way to do row level variances of the balance for each acc. num by period with dax?

I've tried separating the single table in too multiple by filtering periods but can't figure out how to do it by row

Desired output would be the difference in period by account for example 1234 period 2 Balance 300 minus period 1 balance 200 = 100(result im looking for)

Comment: Are you trying to subtract one period from another?  i.e. for `acc.num` 1234, 300 - 200 = `Variance`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do find out the difference in balance between periods for each acc.num

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.  Note that the first balance will be equal to the amount of the first period.

```
MyVariance =
VAR currentBalance =
    SUM ( MyTable[Balance] )
VAR priorBalance =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( MyTable[Balance] ),
        REMOVEFILTERS ( MyTable[Period] ),
        MyTable[Period]
            = MAX ( MyTable[Period] ) - 1
    )
RETURN
    currentBalance - priorBalance
```